# using if binding inside foreach (KnockoutJS)

Tags: knockout.js

I've posted my [question](http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/268b013300ffb0e5) to knockoutJS forum. But I'm not sure if I will get help until tonight. So I'm posting the same question: and It's kind of urgent; I'm waiting for your suggestions:

The View:

```
<select data-bind="foreach: groups"> 
    <!-- ko if: false --> 
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: label}, foreach: children"> 
        <option data-bind="text: label"></option> 
    </optgroup> 
    <!-- /ko --> 
    <!-- ko ifnot: false --> 
    <option data-bind="text: label"></option> 
    <!-- /ko --> 
</select>
```

The JS:

```
function Group(label, children) { 
    this.label = ko.observable(label); 
    this.children = ko.observableArray(children); 
} 

function Option(label) { 
    this.label = ko.observable(label); 
} 

var viewModel = { 
    groups: ko.observableArray([ 
        new Group("Option All", null), 
        new Group("Group 1", [ 
            new Option("Option 1"), 
            new Option("Option 2"), 
            new Option("Option 3") 
            ]), 
        new Group("Group 2", [ 
            new Option("Option 4"), 
            new Option("Option 5"), 
            new Option("Option 6") 
            ]), 
        new Group("Group 3", [ 
            new Option("Option 7"), 
            new Option("Option 8"), 
            new Option("Option 9") 
            ]) 
    ]) 

}; 


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Result:

```
<select> 
    <optGroup>Option All</optGroup> 
    <option>Option All</option> 
    <optGroup label="Group 1"> 
        <option>Option 1</option> 
        <option>Option 2</option> 
        <option>Option 3</option> 
    </optGroup> 
    <option>Group 1</option> 
    <optGroup label="Group 2"> 
        <option>Option 4</option> 
        <option>Option 5</option> 
        <option>Option 6</option> 
    </optGroup> 
    <option>Group 2</option> 
    <optGroup label="Group 3"> 
        <option>Option 7</option> 
        <option>Option 8</option> 
        <option>Option 9</option> 
    </optGroup> 
    <option>Group 3</option> 
</select>
```

Expected Result:

```
<select> 
    <option>Option All</option> 
    <optGroup label="Group 1"> 
        <option>Option 1</option> 
        <option>Option 2</option> 
        <option>Option 3</option> 
    </optGroup> 
    <optGroup label="Group 2"> 
        <option>Option 4</option> 
        <option>Option 5</option> 
        <option>Option 6</option> 
    </optGroup> 
    <optGroup label="Group 3"> 
        <option>Option 7</option> 
        <option>Option 8</option> 
        <option>Option 9</option> 
    </optGroup> 
</select>
```

So, considering the difference between "Result" and "Expected Result" 
what am I doing wrong? Even I give static values to "if" binding like 
"`<!-- ko if: false -->`" it is binding.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Here is your code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/9PmGj/.  It works for me using Safari.  At work we recently had to switch from containerless bindings to get compatibility with IE 7 and IE 8.

Comment: I'm using IE 7. What should I do then? By "containerless binding" you mean jQuery.tmpl?

Comment: Containerless binding is part of the templating built in to knockout 2.0 and replaces jQuery.tmpl which is no longer being developed. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html for more details.

Comment: I've tried the code in Chrome and it's 
working fine. So some features of KnockoutJS doesn't have cross 
browser compability then. 

I've used KO comments inside view because KnockoutJS doesn't let me to 
use both "foreach" and "if" bindings on single Dom element: for 
example 

    <select data-bind="if: false, foreach: groups"> 
        <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: label}, foreach: children"> 
            <option data-bind="text: label"></option> 
        </optgroup> 
        <option data-bind="ifnot: false, text: label"></option> 
    </select>

Comment: this code gives me an error stating that using if and foreach binding 
together is disallowed. So I cannot do such thing in IE7 or IE8? ... 
Too bad. 
I'll try to do the same with jQuery.tmpl then. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Version with mix : Option and Group
Only Group has property children, if has property - group, if not then Option

```
<select data-bind="foreach: groups">
<!-- ko if: $data.hasOwnProperty('children') -->
<optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: label}, foreach: children">
    <option data-bind="text: label"></option>
</optgroup>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: $data.hasOwnProperty('children')  -->
<option data-bind="text: label"></option>
<!-- /ko --></select>

function Group(label, children) {
this.label = ko.observable(label);
this.children = ko.observableArray(children);}


function Option(label) {
this.label = ko.observable(label);}


var viewModel = {
groups: ko.observableArray([
    new Option("Option All"),
    new Group("Option All", [{"label": "Option without object"}]),
    {"label":"OptionGroup Test", "children":[{"label":"label_1"},{"label":"lebel_2"}]},
    new Group("Group 1", [
        new Option("Option 1"),
        new Option("Option 2"),
        new Option("Option 3")
        ]),
    new Option("Option only"),
    new Group("Group 2", [
        new Option("Option 4"),
        new Option("Option 5"),
        new Option("Option 6")
        ]),
    new Group("Group 3", [
        new Option("Option 7"),
        new Option("Option 8"),
        new Option("Option 9")
        ])
])};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem with jquery.tmpl:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
        {{each selectItems}}
            {{if items}}
                <optgroup label="${text}">
                {{each items}}
                    <option value="${value}">${text}</option>
                {{/each}}
                </optgroup>
            {{else}}
                <option value="${value}">${text}</option>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
        </select>
```

And I've solved the problem with KnockoutJS: I've added a custom feature on it.
See [this](http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/268b013300ffb0e5#) link.